# Output only specific var from text

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

Output only specific var from text. In that case:

```
echo "ote -C -pname ap01 -HLS 134 -db 1 -instance 43 -log ap01"
```

Want to get only this value from "-pname"

Exptected result:

```
ap01
```

Comment: Is the string likely to contain `-pname` more than once?

Comment: @fedorqui, Most programs take the latest, but that probably doesn't need to be handled.

Comment: In that scenario should not possible to have more than that option expect of bug in the command ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will deal with a doubled `-pname`.

```
echo "ote -C -pname ap01 -HLS 134 -db 1 -instance 43 -log ap01" |\
    perl -ne 'print ( /\s+-pname\s+([^-]\S*)/ )'
```

---

As ikegami notes below, if you should happen to want to use dashes as the first character of this value, the only way I know that you can be sure you're getting a value and not another switch is more complicated. One way is to do a negative lookahead for all known switches:

```
echo "ote -C -pname -pname -ap01- -HLS 134 -db 1 -instance 43 -log ap01" |\
    perl -ne 'print ( /\s+-pname\s+(?!-(?:pname|other|known|switches))(\S+)/ )'
```

Comment: Note: Assumes `pname`'s value can't start with `-`. May or may not be relevant.

Comment: @ikegami, good point. There are always trade-offs in a quick solution.

Answer (score 5):

`-log` takes a string. That string could be `-pname`. The existing solutions so far fail to handle that and treat the value of the `-log` parameter as the start of another argument.

You'll have to recreate the argument parsing `ote` performs if you want a robust solution. The following is well on your way to do that.

```
echo ... | perl -MGetopt::Long -nle'
   local @ARGV = split;
   GetOptions(\%args, "C", "pname=s", "HLS=i", "db=i", "instant=i", "log=s")
      && defined($args{pname})
         && print($args{pname});
'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "ote -C -pname ap01 -HLS 134 -db 1 -instance 43 -log ap01" | \
    awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {if ($i == "-pname") { print $(i+1); break; } } }'
```

Comment: Fails for `ote -log -pname -pname apo01`

Comment: In that case is very hard to have two options with -pname but good point if we have twice that option!

Comment: @Kalin Borisov, My example only has the `-pname` option once.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` with look behind?

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=-pname )[^ ]*' <<< "ote -C -pname ap01 -HLS 134 -db 1 -instance 43 -log ap01"
ap01
```

As there might be many `-pname` in the string (see comments below), you can then "play" with `head` and `tail` to get the value you want.

#### Explanation

- This uses `-P` for Perl Regex and `-o` for "print only the matched parts of a machine line".
- `(?<=-pname )` is a look-behind: match strings that are preceeded by `-pname` (note the space).
- `[^ ]*` match any set of characters until a space is found.

Comment: Still fails for `ote -pname apo01 -log -pname -C`

Comment: Well, the OP says `In that scenario should not possible to have more than that option expect of bug in the command ...` But in general it is a matter of using `head` or `tail` depending on the case. More context from the OP would help.

Comment: There's only one instance of the `-pname` option in my examples. head or tail is not going to help you get the right value. You gotta stop treating the log file name as the start of a parameter.

Comment: @ikegami yes it does. Check `grep -Po '(?<=-pname )[^ ]*' <<< "ote -C -pname -pname ap01 -HLS 134 -db 1 -instance 43 -log ap01"` in your shell. It returns two lines: first with `-pname` and second with `ap01`.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "ote -C -pname ap01 -HLS 134 -db 1 -instance 43 -log ap01" | \
  perl -pe '($_)= /-pname\s+([^-]\S*)/'
```

Comment: This is Axeman's solution, and the same note applies: Assumes `pname`'s value can't start with `-`. May or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use (GNU) `grep`:

```
$ echo "ote -C -pname ap01 -HLS 134 -pname foo -db 1 -instance 43 -log ap01" |
     grep -Po -- '-pname \K[^ ]+'
ap01
```

#### Explanation

The `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCREs) which gives us `\K` (meaning "discard anything matched up to this point). The `-o` means "print only the matched portion of the line. So, we then look for the string `-pname` followed by a space and then as many consecutive non-space characters as possible (`[^ ]+`). Because of the `\K`, everything before that is discarded and because of the `-o`, only the matched portion is printed.

This will work for an arbitrary number of `-pname` flags as long as none of their values contain spaces.

Comment: You here! Funny, it returns `ap01` and `foo` to me. I had a slightly similar approach and got some comments regarding this.

Comment: @fedorqui quina sorpresa! :)  Yes, I used the `foo` to test for cases with >1 `-pname` and forgot to change the output in my answer. Edited. It's supposed to return both. This one also works for `-pname -pname` though.

Answer (score 1):

This looks simple

```
xargs -n1 | sed -n "/-pname/,//p" | tail -n1
```